# Ranking Aggregate Field in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to rank an aggregate field in access but my efforts are in vain with errors based on referencing. I am ranking using a subquery but the problem comes about due to the alias names resulting from performing an average on a field. The code is as below:

```
SELECT [Exams].[StudentID],
       Avg([Exams].[Biology]) AS [AvgBiology],
       (SELECT Avg(T.Biology) AS [TAvgBiology],
               Count(*)
        FROM   [Exams] AS T
        WHERE  T.[TAvgBiology] > [AvgBiology])
       + 1                    AS Rank
FROM   [Exams]
GROUP  BY [Exams].[StudentID]
ORDER  BY Avg([Exams].[Biology]) DESC;
```

Errors that come about state: "You have selected a subquery that can return more than one value blah blah...please use the Exist keyword.. ".
From the code above I think you get the gist of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  You have an aggregation function but no `group by`.  Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the basic `GROUP BY` query [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) suggested to compute the average *Biology* for each *StudentID*.

```sql
SELECT
    e.StudentID,
    Avg(e.Biology) AS AvgBiology
FROM Exams AS e
GROUP BY e.StudentID
```

Save that query as *qryAvgBiology* and then use it in another query where you compute *Rank*.

```sql
SELECT
    q.StudentID,
    q.AvgBiology, 
    (
        (
            SELECT Count(*)
            FROM qryAvgBiology AS q2
            WHERE q2.AvgBiology > q.AvgBiology
        )
        +1
    ) AS Rank
FROM qryAvgBiology AS q
ORDER BY 3;
```

For example, if *qryAvgBiology* returns this result set ...

```sql
StudentID AvgBiology
--------- ----------
        1         70
        2         80
        3         90
```

The ranking query will transform it to this ...

```sql
StudentID AvgBiology Rank
--------- ---------- ----
        3         90    1
        2         80    2
        1         70    3
```

Comment: I did it that way previously but considering the amount of queries of this nature I will be having does not go well by me. Is there any way to include it all in one query. Thanks for the reply HansUp.

NB: Most of my queries will not use the actual values but will be performing different forms of performance analysis with ranking involved. An all inclusive method will be 'life saving'.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your basic query is:

```
SELECT e.StudentId Avg(e.Biology) AS AvgBiology
FROM exams as e
GROUP BY e.StudentId;
```

(Square braces don't help me understand the query at all.)

I think the following will work in Access:

```
SELECT e.StudentId Avg(e.Biology) AS AvgBiology,
       (SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
        FROM (SELECT e.StudentId, Avg(e.Biology) AS AvgBiology
              FROM exams as e
              GROUP BY e.StudentId
             ) e2
        WHERE e2.AvgBiology > Avg(e.Biology)
       ) as ranking
FROM exams as e
GROUP BY e.StudentId;
```

Comment: Cannot have an aggregate function in  `WHERE e2.AvgBiology > Avg(e.Biology)`